# kafka-log4j-appender 0.9.0.1 omits throwable information for errors

Tags: java, log4j, apache-kafka, appender

Looks like kafka-log4j-appender 0.9.0.1 omits throwable information when send message to Kafka.
I am using following configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.com.doublev=INFO, KAFKA

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA=org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.KAFKA.brokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.topic=logs
log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncSend=false
```

Example output in the console:

```
ERROR [main] (App.java:21) - / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.doublev.sls.test.App.main(App.java:19)
```

And on Kafka side it receives:

```
ERROR [main] (App.java:21) - / by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

Kafka appender has quite extensive set of settings. Please see the following:

```
log4j.appender.KAFKA.compressionType=none
log4j.appender.KAFKA.requiredNumAcks=0
log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncSend=true  //did you try false here?
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Serializer=kafka.producer.DefaultStringEncoder
```

also please use

```
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

as according to **log4j** java doc

> The **PatternLayout** does not handle the throwable contained within
>   LoggingEvents.

Comment: Thanks for a fresh idea with EnhancedPatternLayout, I finally came along with the configuration I added in the next answer

Answer (score 1):

The final configuration that works for me is the following:

```
log4j.appender.KAFKA=org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n%throwable
log4j.appender.KAFKA.brokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.topic=logs
log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncSend=false
```

I also figured out why strack trace is printed for `ConsoleAppender` and `PatternLayout`. Throwable information is handled by `ConsoleAppender` predecessor - `WriterAppender`:

```
protected
  void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
    this.qw.write(this.layout.format(event));

    if(layout.ignoresThrowable()) {
      String[] s = event.getThrowableStrRep();
      if (s != null) {
    int len = s.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      this.qw.write(s[i]);
      this.qw.write(Layout.LINE_SEP);
    }
      }
    }

    if(shouldFlush(event)) {
      this.qw.flush();
    }
  }
```